# Linked List Operations C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, linked-list

I've got a linked list data base using templates which compiles fine and lets me print out a list of all states and lets me search for a person and print all that persons data (since these methods work, I left them out below to save space).

Below I have a `print_people_in_state` method, what I need to be able to do is to (given a user input of state) print out the info on all the people from that particular state. However right now when I run it, nothing happens. How can I fix this?

If you want to run the code yourself here is a link to the file that I named data.txt (http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/class/een118/labs/152/dbfile1.txt)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


struct person
{
    int dob,ss_number;
    string fname, lname,state;

    person()
    { }
    person(int a, int b, string c, string d, string e)
    {dob=a; ss_number=b; fname=c; lname=d; state=e;}
};


struct state
{
    string sname;
    person*P;


    state()
    {}
    state(string a)
    {sname=a;}
};

template<typename T>struct Link
{
    T*data;
    Link*extradata;
    Link*next;

    Link()
    {}
    Link(T*a,Link<T>*C=NULL)
    {
        data=a;
        next=C;

    }

};
template<typename T>
struct List
{int length;
    Link<T>*Head,*tail;
    List(Link<T>*h=NULL, Link<T>*t=NULL)
    {
        Head=h;
        tail=t;
        length=0;
    }

    void add(T*object)
    {
        {   if (Head == NULL && tail == NULL)
        {   Link<T> * newlink = new Link<T>(object);
            Head = newlink;
            tail = Head;  }
        else
        {   Link<T> * newlink = new Link<T>(object);
            tail->next = newlink;
            tail=newlink;} }
    }
void print_people_in_state(string search)
{

   Link<state>*temp=Head;
   if(temp!==NULL)
       {
          if(temp->data->P->state==search)
             {
               cout<<temp->data->P->fname<<endl;
              }
       //  temp=temp->next;
}}




};
List<person>*person_from_file(string file)//reads file 
{
    List<person>* newlist=new List<person>();
    //        Link<T> * head=NULL;
    //        Link<T> * temp=NULL;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("data.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
        cout<<"file not found\n";
    if (!fin.fail())
    {
        while(true)
        {
            int a,b;
            string c,d,e;
            fin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;
            if (fin.fail())break;
            person * p=new person(a,b,c,d,e);
            newlist->add(p);


        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"Can't open file";
    fin.close();
    return newlist;
}
List<state>*state_from_file(string file)//reads file 
{
    List<state>* newlist=new List<state>();
    //        Link<T> * head=NULL;
    //        Link<T> * temp=NULL;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("data.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
        cout<<"file not found\n";
    if (!fin.fail())
    {
        while(true)
        {
            int a,b;
            string c,d,e;
            fin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;
            if (fin.fail())break;
            state * s=new state(e);
            newlist->add(s);


        }
    }
    else
        cout<<"Can't open file";
    fin.close();
    return newlist;
}

int main()
{List<person>*A = person_from_file("data.txt");
 List<state> *B= state_from_file("data.txt");



       B->print_people_in_state("TX");



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to iterate through the linked-list in `print_people_in_state()`, I guess.

Comment: The line `if(state==search)` you need to use `if(state.compare(search)`.  I believe

Comment: Sorry that should be `if(!state.compare(search))`

Comment: Here's a basic design tip: never add problem specific functions in a generic container.  You should instead pass a predicate to a find method that's responsible to comparing the internals of your Link's Nodes

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify `Link` and `List`. You can read the file once and fill both lists at the same time. In fact, you don't really need a separate list for states, its usage is confusing.

```
template<typename T>class Link
{
public:
    Link(T *data) { Data = data; Next = NULL; }
    T *Data;
    Link<T> *Next;
};

template<typename T>struct List
{
    int Count;
    Link<T> *Head, *Tail;
    List() { Head = NULL; Tail = NULL; Count = 0; }

    Link<T>* AddData(T *data)
    {
        Link<T> *node = new Link<T>(data);
        Count++;
        if (Head == NULL)
        {
            Head = Tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            Tail->Next = node;
            Tail = node;
        }
        return node;
    }
};

int main()
{
    List<person> *list = new List<person>;

    ifstream fin("data.txt");
    while (fin)
    {
        int a, b;
        string c, d, e;
        fin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
        list->AddData(new person(a, b, c, d, e));
    }

    Link<person> *node = list->Head;
    while (node)
    {
        if (node->Data->state == "TX")
            cout << node->Data->fname << endl;
        node = node->Next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```